# How to query indexed values in XML column using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I am needing to query for all the id values in the XML column below and needing some help doing that. How do I use the index values in my select statement? Any help/direction would be appreciated. Thanks.

Here is the XML file:

```
<rotation>
    <adjuster id="3381" index="0" />
    <adjuster id="7629" index="1" />
    <adjuster id="10087" index="2" />
    <adjuster id="10741" index="3" />
    <adjuster id="11544" index="4" />
    <adjuster id="12367" index="5" />
</rotation>
```

Here is my select statement but only getting the first value returned:

```
select 
    t.AssignmentRotation.value('(/rotation/adjuster/@id)[1]','varchar(max)') as adjuster_id 
from 
    dbo.CMS_AdjusterTeam t 
where 
    t.AdjusterTeamSysID IN (5, 6);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following snippet illustrate how to extract all Id and index values:

```
declare @xml xml = N'<rotation>
    <adjuster id="3381" index="0" />
    <adjuster id="7629" index="1" />
    <adjuster id="10087" index="2" />
    <adjuster id="10741" index="3" />
    <adjuster id="11544" index="4" />
    <adjuster id="12367" index="5" />
</rotation>'

select Id = rt.aj.value('@id', 'varchar(5000)'),
    [Index] = rt.aj.value('@index', 'varchar(5000)')
    from (select XmlData = @xml) t
    cross apply t.XmlData.nodes('//rotation/adjuster') rt(aj)
```

So your final query would be looking like:

```
select rt.aj.value('@id','varchar(max)') as adjuster_id 
from dbo.CMS_AdjusterTeam t 
cross apply t.AssignmentRotation.nodes('//rotation/adjuster') rt(aj)
WHERE t.AdjusterTeamSysID IN (5, 6);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and help.  I could not find this when googling.